# UI Designer for Editing Web.config in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I need rich UI designer for editing the web.config for ASP.net application.
From the designer We can edit the tags in config files

It may be any windows application going to edit my config files.

Answer (score 2):

ASPhere is a nice Windows GUI app for editing web.config:

- [ASPhere](http://asphere.aspweb.cz/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is excellent for this by itself, as it automatically picks up schemas (.xsd files) that are either in your solution or in the Schemas folder.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas
```

Make sure that this folder contains the required xsd files:

- DotNetConfig20.xsd
- DotNetConfig30.xsd
- ...

These should be picked up by default.

It may help if you remove the default namespace declaration in your config file. If you have this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

change it into this:

```
<configuration>
```

That helped me to enable intellisense. Thanks to Scott Gu btw:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/02/432077.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to accomplish? Web.config is just an XML file, and there are loads of good XML editors available. However, using Visual Studio 2008 gives you full IntelliSense support. The IIS web server manager also has a built-in graphical editor, but you'll need web server access for that.